# How to create control statements for file IO

Tags: ruby

In a file, I have a list of e-mail addresses, and I want to display only those that end with a certain domain name (i.e. `gmail.com`). I want to include a regular expression in an `if`-`else` statement. Should the code be like this?

```
File.open("my/file/path", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    if line =~ /gmail\.com/
        print "Hello"
    end
  end
end
```

When I ran it, it gave me errors starting at line 3, so I am wondering what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the error message...

```
test.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from test.rb:2:in `each_line'
    from test.rb:2:in `block in <main>'
    from test.rb:1:in `open'
    from test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Have you tried `puts "Hello"`

Comment: The error message had something to do with UTF-8 something. I forgot the rest @sawa. And I think 'puts' and 'prints' are the same thing

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a regex to do it?

Comment: Is there another way? @sawa

Comment: Any suggestions? @sawa

Comment: If I were to use the regex approach, how would I write it? @sawa

Comment: Your code is correct. The problem is with encoding, which is outside of what you posted.

Comment: If you don't recall the error message why don't you just re-run the code to see what it is? Please report both the message and the line where it occurred. Error messages generally contain valuable information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have to give us accurate information if you want help. Please read "[ask]", including the links at the bottom of the page, and "[mcve]". As is you've asked a broad question because you didn't tell us enough, so you'll get broad answers, which is not what SO is about, resulting in an off-topic question. Also give us a minimal input example and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, I tried to do the same. Anyway, you can also try

```
if line.end_with? "gmail.com"
```

In any case, I think you have a strange character in your code. Maybe you put it with a copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to write your code in a more Ruby-like way:

```
File.foreach('my/file/path') do |line|
  print "Hello" if line =~ /gmail\.com$/
end
```

Rather than opening the file, then iterating over it using `each_line`, `foreach` does both in one step.

Using a trailing `if` if more readable if you only have a simple conditional test or action being taken.

Using `$` (or `\z`) at the end of the regex anchors the search to the end of the line (or string). That avoids a false-positive if the string contained `'gmail.com'` mid-string:

```
'foo.gmail.com.baz'[/gmail\.com/]    # => "gmail.com"
'foo.gmail.com.baz'[/gmail\.com$/]   # => nil
'foo.gmail.com.baz'[/gmail\.com\z/]  # => nil

'foo.gmail.com'[/gmail\.com/]    # => "gmail.com"
'foo.gmail.com'[/gmail\.com$/]   # => "gmail.com"
'foo.gmail.com'[/gmail\.com\z/]  # => "gmail.com"
```

This probably won't fix the problem you're seeing but it will make your code more readable and behave more as you expect.